# MySql - Is an index on a column redundant if it is defined as unique?

Tags: sql, mysql, indexing

If a table is defined to have a unique constraint on a column, is it also necessary to define a separate index on that column if we want it to be indexed for fast lookup?

For example, given the following table indexes:

```
mysql> show index from FRONTIER;
+----------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+-------------+---------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name                | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+----------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| FRONTIER |          0 | PRIMARY                 |            1 | ID           | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| FRONTIER |          0 | uniq_cnstr              |            1 | HOST_ID      | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| FRONTIER |          0 | uniq_cnstr              |            2 | HASH_PATHQRY | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| FRONTIER |          1 | I_FRONTIER_HASH_PATHQRY |            1 | HASH_PATHQRY | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+----------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

Is the index 'I_FRONTIER_HASH_PATHQRY' redundant given unique constraint 'uniq_constr' ?

(note that the  unique constraint spans 2 columns)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A unique index is a plain index as well, there is no need to create a separate non-unique one.

However, your unique constraint covers two columns `(host_id, hash_pathqry)`, the `hash_pathqry` being trailing.

An index maintains the lexicographical order of columns, so `hash_pathqry` are only ordered within each single value of `host_id`.

So the unique index you already have will not improve the lookups on `HASH_PATHQRY`. The `I_FRONTIER_HASH_PATHQRY` is still required.

Comment: @Joel: if the column were leading, you wouldn't have to create a separate index. But it's trailing so you still have to.

Comment: Thanks, so if I understand correctly if the order of two columns in the unique constraint were reversed then no additional index would be required on the 'leading' column  'I_FRONTIER_HASH_PATHQRY' ?

Comment: @Joel: correct, but in this case an index on `host_id` would be required if you wanted to lookup on the latter.

Answer (score 0):

no - if you specify unique i.e username varbinary(32) unique not null, then MySQL adds a unique index automatically.

Comment: apparently not, see Quassnoi's comment  re: unique constraints spanning multiple columns.

Comment: @Joel: in case of multiple columns, a single composite unique index on these columns will be created. `MySQL` always polices the unique constraints with unique indices, so @f00's statement is correct (though it's not an answer to your question).

Comment: @all - my bad, "defined to have a unique index on a column" to be literally one column